# CheckPoint VPN and video stream

Tags: streaming, vlc, vpn

So I have a web site streaming the ip cameras from work, using vlc plugin. Works perfectly in every computer, except the ones that have Check Point installed. It will not display the streaming unless I uninstall the client.
The problem uninstalling the client is less than ideal. Anyone knows why and how to fix this?